# Calculate percentage similarity of two images using OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I am able to find matching features using bewlow shown code. I want to calculate percentage similarity between two images. I am new to OpenCV. Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

```
    FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB);
    DescriptorExtractor extractor = DescriptorExtractor
            .create(DescriptorExtractor.ORB);

    detector.detect(image1, keypoints1);
    detector.detect(image2, keypoints2);

    extractor.compute(image1, keypoints1, descriptors1);
    extractor.compute(image2, keypoints2, descriptors2);

    DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher
            .create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING);

    MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();
    matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);
```

Is there any other library available serving the same purpose?

Comment: Did my answer help? Could you find a better way?

Comment: I am kinda novice to image processing, so it took time to understand certain terms. Yet I need to implement this while I explore other libraries like pHash and pdiff.

Comment: @SorryBoss: Can you tell me how did you do the comparison of images ? I am also trying for the same can you give some lead or code in android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two libraries [pHash](http://phash.org/) and [pdiff](http://pdiff.sourceforge.net/) offering what I am looking for. I'll evaluate their performance and as well as compatibility with my code and pick the best one.

Comment: I know it was years ago, but may I ask did you solve your problem? I need exactly what you needed. Would you share your progress?

Comment: Hey ftb, I can't recall what did we end up using and unfortunately, I don't have access to that codebase anymore

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can compute a percentage *per se* by using feature points. But you can compute a "score of similarity".

First of all, you want to filter out the bad matches you have, in some way (I would use a homography transformation to geometrically validate the matches). Then, you can establish your own way of computing this "score of similarity".

For instance, you can simply sum the hamming distances between the matches you have. And you could also use the position of the feature points: Suppose a feature point *Ai* on image *A* has a correspondence *Bi* on image *B*. The coordinates of *Ai* are *(Xa, Ya)* and those of *Bi* are *(Xb, Yb)*. For your images to be similar, you possibly want *(Xa, Ya)* to be as close as possible to *(Xb, Yb)*. The score would then be something like:

```
Score = HammingDist / DistanceBetween(Point(Xa, Ya), Point(Xb, Yb))
```

And of course, you might want to put more weight on `HammingDist` or on `DistanceBetween`; you need to experiment.